# Unified finger print reader API

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, biometrics

I have a program that requires finger print authentication, but I am trying to find a way to develop this once, for all types of finger print readers; is that possible? Or do I just have to pick one of them and develop my program according to it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277373/is-there-a-fingerprint-reader-api-sdk

Comment: I've seen it, it is in 2008, I hoped that I can find some new unified api

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Windows Biometric Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463081), assuming you can restrict your application to Windows 7/Server 2008 or better.